# How to connect MongoDB cluster to my app correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to connect a cluster to Node.js app and all I'm getting is an `authentication fail` error. I've been trying to fix it for a while now and at this point I'm really frustrated.

This is how my code looks like:

```
const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;
 mongoose
  .connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

The mongoURI looks something like this:

```
mongodb+srv://namehere:<passwordhere>@cluster0-bhve1.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true
```

I keep getting this error:

```
{ MongoError: authentication fail
    at C:\Users\AyaLe\Desktop\nodes\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\replset.js:1458:15
    at C:\Users\AyaLe\Desktop\nodes\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:869:7
    at C:\Users\AyaLe\Desktop\nodes\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:845:20
    at finish (C:\Users\AyaLe\Desktop\nodes\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\auth\scram.js:233:16)
    at handleEnd (C:\Users\AyaLe\Desktop\nodes\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\auth\scram.js:243:7)
    at C:\Users\AyaLe\Desktop\nodes\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\auth\scram.js:352:15
    at C:\Users\AyaLe\Desktop\nodes\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:532:18
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
  errors:
   [ { name: 'cluster0-shard-00-00-bhve1.mongodb.net:27017',
       err: [MongoError] },
     { name: 'cluster0-shard-00-02-bhve1.mongodb.net:27017',
       err: [MongoError] },
     { name: 'cluster0-shard-00-01-bhve1.mongodb.net:27017',
       err: [MongoError] } ],
  name: 'MongoError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Comment: `{ useNewUrlParser: true, authSource: "admin"  }`

Comment: Can I see your connection string, just replace the USER and PASS with test or someting? :) I had no problem running your code so it may be in your connection string

Comment: I've set the username and the password the same ```mongodb+srv://aya:<aya>@cluster0-bhve1.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true``` I've also added ```authSource: "admin" ``` but still doesn't work